# callback Button Click event in Ant Design React

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on a project that uses AntDesign. The layout has a default header style with icons which are set in the props:

```
const Header = () => {
  const headerProps = {
    title: "VIEWER",
    iconsBefore: [
      { icon: { set: "antd", type: "Layers" } },
      { icon: { set: "antd", type: "close" } },
    ],
    iconsAfter: [
      { icon: { set: "antd", type: "Levels" } },
      { icon: { set: "antd", type: "share-alt" } },
    ],
  };

  return (
    <Layout>
// Props are passed into the header bar here
      <Layout.Header {....headerProps}>
        <Button type={`close`} closeFunction={closeFunction} />
      </Layout.Header>
    </Layout>
  );
};

export default Topbar;
```

This is a pattern that I haven't used before and is possibly incorrect so I have a question regarding this pattern. How do you call an onClick event to the specified icon in the props.

Comment: which version of ant.design are you using?

Comment: "antd": "3.26.9"